# catch error from iframe playing live video

Tags: java, android, video, iframe

I am trying to make a live video stream app using webview iframe. Here is the script...

```
    String html = "<iframe allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowtransparency=\"true\" class=\"\" height=\"265.05\" id=\"player\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"my video url here" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
    WebView webview;
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webVid);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
```

The video is playing fine in iframe but the problem is when i pause the video for a long time like 2 min and play the video again it just never resume or play.

in the console i am getting this error...

```
    Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://ind14-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ind14_eboxtv@156617/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1511009127~exp=1511009487~acl=/i/ind14_eboxtv@156617/*~hmac=fedfd5ca85ebc519cd5d1b64f85b27bf72a9035f1c3957fc3f3273cd9b6d49d4
    Unable to configure metadata extractor
    E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
    E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)
```

Is there any way to catch the errors so that i can refresh the iframe when i get this errors.